# What does this inserted clause mean? 文法だけなくて

Tags: negation

> 日本語と英語は、文法だけなくて、考え方随分違うらしい。

It is saying that: evidently, the way of thinking in English and Japanese is extremely different.

What does the 文法だけなくて? (Grammar only ...?)
I always get confused when なくて appears in a sentence. It is as if i am bracing for some contradiction or negative.

Is their a general phrase pattern for 「~なくて」？

Comment: Please check the sentence again. It would be 文法だけでなくて.

Comment: Yes, 文法だけでなくて means "not only grammar" but 文法だけなくて means "only grammar missing".

Comment: Also it should be 考え方**も**随分違うらしい, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence should be:

> 日本語と英語は、文法だけ**で**なくて、考え方**も**随分違うらしい。

「XXだけでなくてYYも」（or 「XXだけでなくYYも」「XXだけではなくYYも」「XXだけではなくてYYも」etc.) means "Not only XX but also YY".

So it literally means:

"As for Japanese and English, it seems / they say that not only their grammars but also their ways of thinking are quite different."
→ "It seems / they say that Japanese and English are quite different not only in grammar but also in way of thinking."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's say that English and Japanese are, not limited to grammatical aspects, very different languages.